# Crashlytics / Fabric: disable notification for older app versions

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Crashlytics / Fabric: disable email notification for older app versions, is that possible? I cannot find it in the interface.

If I disable the older versions completely, not only the notifications, I am afraid I won't receive any crashlogs anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Currently it's not possible to disable notifications on a per versions basis and disabling an older version would prevent new crash reports from coming in. You could close and lock issues that you don't want to get more information from. Crash reports would still flow in, but if an issue is locked, it wouldn't be re-opened and thus notifications wouldn't be sent.

Comment: Thank you, closing them is okay but then new errors still come in with notifications. Can I post "turn notifications off for specific versions" as a feature request somewhere?

Comment: Noted as a request :)